# How to block localhost in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to block localhost in firebase and only allow my secure domain. I've tried using the "Authorized domain" in the sign-in method but it's not blocking the localhost. is there any way to allow only certain url/domain on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete `localhost` from your list of authorized domains. Hover over the row in the Firebase Console. The trash bin icon will appear on the right side of the row and you can click that to delete that domain.

Note this affects phone auth and OAuth domains only. Firebase Auth does not perform domain checks on email/password sign in.