# Secure basic Firebase form for newsletter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to create a newsletter subscription form. Meaning a user can register to my newsletter without creating an account.

I would like to do a simple insertion. But what is the best way to secure it ?

I have implemented "Anonymous Log In" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)

I need basic rules, `read` to check is the user is allready registered and `write` to push user data into Realtime DB.

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

when the Anonymous Login is done, I push into the Realtime Database.

```
let dbConnection = firebase.database().ref('/newsletter_user');
dbConnection.push(datas).then(callback);
```

The problem is that Anonymous Auth do not check Auth Domain. ([How to block localhost in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905761/how-to-block-localhost-in-firebase))

Meaning a user can grab my ApiKey and perform insert or read data into my realbase database.

Then it do not seems really secure to me. What can I do to improve security ?

Comment: What isn't secure about it? E.g. what code could now be run successfully, that you want to fail? Once you know that, you can adapt your security rules to match that requirement.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen
rules works well, meaning, user have to make an anonymous auth before to be able to push data on realtime database. But the anonymous auth always succeed... I have remove "localhost" from "Authorized domains" for "Authentication" to perform a test, but I can stil make an anonymous auth from my localhost... any clue ?

Comment: So are you asking why you can sign in anonymously from localhost, when you've remove localhost from the authorized domains? That's a valid question, but quite different from your original post.

Comment: You are right, i have updated the post, also because I have round an explanation about AuthDomain but still trying to find a way to secure my form. Maybe Captcha ? Not really sure neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can do to improve your security is limiting your database access. Currently you have basic read/write rules for your database wich means that someone that is authenticated can do **anything** in your database. If I want I could write an entire encyclopedia in your `datadump` node :)

So the first thing you can do is limit read/write access to specific locations:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "newsletter_user" : {
       ".read": "auth != null",
       ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can only do something under the `newsletter_user` node.

Next you can use [validation rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data) to make sure only the data you want can be written:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "newsletter_user" : {
       ".read": "auth != null",
       ".write": "auth != null",
       // a valid newsletter_user must have attributes "color" and "size"
       // allows deleting newsletter_user (since .validate is not applied to delete rules)
       ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['color', 'size'])",
       "size": {
         // the value of "size" must be a number between 0 and 99
         ".validate": "newData.isNumber() &&
                  newData.val() >= 0 &&
                  newData.val() <= 99"
       },
       "color": {
         // the value of "color" must exist as a key in our mythical
         // /valid_colors/ index
         ".validate": "root.child('valid_colors/' + newData.val()).exists()"
       }
    }
  }
}
```